# Multiple Definitions compiling errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, multiple-definition-error

My first post on StackExchange!
I have an assignment for my C++ course; to make an Appointment Class that uses a previous assignment of a Date class (month, day, year) and a Time class (Hour, Minute, AM/PM).
I think I have most of the primary/syntax errors out of the way.

My problem is that with how I've currently done the #includes and header files, I get a **multiple definitions error** *of the constructors for Date and Time.* (And I don't know much about Templates, but I'm required to work with them.)

My files:

- Appointment.cpp

  ```
  #include "time.cpp"
  #include "date.cpp"
  #include "appointment.h"
  ```

  I need to be able to create a Time/Date object, should I use .h or .cpp files?
- Appointment.h

  ```
  #ifndef _APPOINTMENT_H_
  #define _APPOINTMENT_H_
  #include <iostream>
  #include "time.h"
  #include "date.h"
  ```
- date.cpp

  ```
  #ifndef _DATE_CPP_
  #define _DATE_CPP_
  #include "date.h"
  ```
- date.h

  ```
  #ifndef _DATE_H_
  #define _DATE_H_
  ```
- time.cpp

  ```
  #ifndef _TIME_CPP_
  #define _TIME_CPP_
  #include "time.h"
  ```
- time.h

  ```
  #ifndef _TIME_H_
  #define _TIME_H_
  ```

The following are related to implementation of the above files:

- main.cpp

  ```
  #include "arrayListType.h"
  #include "appointment.h"

  void read(arrayListType<Appointment>&);
  void output(const arrayListType<Appointment>&);

  int main()
  {
     arrayListType<Appointment> appointments;
     read(appointments);
     output(appointments);
     return 0;
  }
  ```
- read.cpp

  ```
  #include "arrayListType.h"
  #include "appointment.h"
  #include <fstream>
  using namespace std;

  void read(arrayListType<Appointment>& appointments)
  {...}
  ```
- output.cpp

  ```
  #include "arrayListType.h"
  #include "appointment.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  using namespace std;

  void output(const arrayListType<Appointment>& appointments)
  {...}
  ```
- arrayListType.h (which has all of the implementation in, as templates)
- itemType.h

Not sure if you need to see the last 2. If I need to post more information, I'm glad to. I have a compressed version of all the files too.

Comment: You're using [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Only include header files not source units

Comment: I do not see the respective closing `#endif` for each header file.  Are they present?

Comment: Yeah, I kept out the #endif (s) just to keep the post as short as possible.

Comment: What happens now with the removal of the `.cpp` inclusions?

Comment: @OpenLearner, if I use the header files, then how will the header file access the implementation of it?

Comment: Perhaps some review material about the C++ compiler and linker will help.  There must be something that is in your book clarifying how the pre-processor does its work, then compiling, then linking per directions in a makefile.  Keep in mind that a makefile is optional.  All of the compiling and linking commands can be individually executed at the command line.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD, linking files is nothing new to our class. Been doing it for awhile, but I just don't see the connection from one .cpp class that #includes date.h to be able to create a object without being able to access date.cpp

Comment: Well, the short answer is that including the header file is necessary in order for a `.cpp` file to know enough class signature details to correctly obtain the actual details in the linker stage.  This should already have been discussed as part of the C and C++ basics in the course and book.

Comment: I agree that you need to review some basics on how C++ compilation and linking happens. Will make your life much easier if you actually understand what they are doing, and a single question on stack overflow is not likely going to resolve the confusion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from Appointment.cpp:

```
#include "time.cpp"
#include "date.cpp"
```

You should almost never include a `.cpp` file from another one. As such, you can also remove the include guards that you have in your `.cpp` files, since you won't be including them.

These lines from `main.cpp` need to be in a header file which is included from `main.cpp` and from the `.cpp` file that implements the function:

```
void read(arrayListType<Appointment>&);
void output(const arrayListType<Appointment>&);
```

You seem to be missing the point of header files. The idea is to separate *interface* and *implementation*. The header file provides everything that a different unit needs to know in order to be able to call the functions listed in the header.  The `.cpp` file actually does the work once the functions have been called; and the other units don't need to know how that works , just so long as it meets the "contract" specified by the header file.

I'd also suggest some more changes to avoid possible clashes:

- Change `"time.h"` to something else; there's a standard header called `<time.h>` and it's easy to have your compiler or system environment set up slightly wrong and end up including the wrong one
- use the format `H_APPOINTMENT` for the header guard token.  Identifiers starting with `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved; as are all-caps identifiers starting with `E`.